# "Automatically update time in PHP using Ajax - display

Tags: php, ajax

I wish to show the current local time on my weather web site.

This is the code that I use from a query :"Automatically update time in PHP using Ajax" posted 2 years ago

```
<?php 
echo "<html>
    <head>
        <title>Realtime clock</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             setInterval(_initTimer, 1000);
         });
         function _initTimer(){
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'timer.php',
                 success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                     data = data.split(':');
                     $('#hrs').html(data[0]);
                     $('#mins').html(data[1]);
                     $('#secs').html(data[2]);
                 }
             });
         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id='hrs'>0</span>:<span id='mins'>0</span>:<span id='secs'>0</span>
    </body>
</html>";  ?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Brisbane");
echo "Current Time: ". date("H:i:s"). " AEST";
?>
```

This is what I getwhen I run this:

17:05:10 Current Time: 17:01:30 AEST

What I am aiming to achieve is:
Current Time: 17:05:10 AEST with the time updating every second.
Is there some addition that I need to make in the final echo  statement? Or do something else

please help

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the time on your server is off by 4 minutes

Comment: Yes, the 17:01:30 was the time when the whole page was reloaded whilst the 17:05:10 was the time generated by the above script and updated every second.  the last line of code is what I am wanting to achieve.  Please help with that, if you are able.

Answer (score 0):

To show current time every second you could use jquery to show time, instead of running ajax on server for every second

**Try this:**

```js
var nIntervId;

function updateTime() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(flashTime, 1000);
}

function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }

Number.prototype.pad = function (len) {
    return (new Array(len+1).join("0") + this).slice(-len);
}

function flashTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours().pad(2);
    var m = now.getMinutes().pad(2);
    var s = now.getSeconds().pad(2);
    var time = h + ' : ' + m + ' : ' + s;
    $('#my_box1').html(time);
}

$(function() {
    updateTime();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="my_box1">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have made a separate timer.php file just to echo server time. As your current page is loading just once, the initial server time will not be updated that is your "current time value". Whereas the remaining DOM will be updated with the server time because of ajax code. If you want both times to be same you will have to reload the whole page which is not correct. Hence, I suggest you to display only one time which should be your ajax result.
timer.php:

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Brisbane");
 echo date("H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What I am trying to achieve is to have the server time included between : "Current time:" and "AEST".  That is what I was trying to achieve with the last line of my code but that code doesn't give me the result that I need.  Please help,

Comment: Use ajax for "AEST", so now one ajax code will display your server time and another ajax code for showing "AEST" which you might want to run after some time elapsed like after 5sec. but this way there the value will always have some difference